# Devise: Get Date of User's last activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know that Devise allows you to get the last sign in time for a user (with last_sign_in_at), but **is there a way to get the date of the last activity the user performs**?  I allow people to stay signed into their account, but I would like to check when they were last seen on the site.

In my app, users can create projects, make comments, favorite projects, etc.  It seems unreasonable to check the last date any of these actions were done and use that for the last seen date.  Is there something built into Devise to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really devise's job to keep track of this - it is only an authentication library. What constitutes an action is business logic, you should implement it into your models.
Perhaps the simplest way to do this would be adding in your models something like:

`belongs_to :user, :touch => true`

This means that every time a resource has been updated, the user that resource belongs to will  have the `updated_at` field set to the current datetime.

Comment: can we use touch to update column other than `updated_at`? I don't want to use `updated_at` for this purpose because in my case user can be updated by other user. So, If one user updates other, then it will be considered active whereas it might not be.